# Gantt Chart Scale Zoom

Tags: 2013, task-list, chart

Is there a way to have scaling or even the zoom in zoom out functionality on a Task List Gantt Chart view in a Web Part on a dashboard.

It's part of a dashboard and rather than going into the task list to then use the zoom, is there not a way to do this within the webpart.

I'm stumped. Tried adding a CEWP with JS from one of the other forum posts but it just duplicated my Task List Gantt.

Thanks.